# How did SCP-3848 affect human morality?

Tags: short-stories, morality, scp-foundation

I was reading the SCP Foundation wiki as well as TVTropes and read about the interesting story of the ED-K-Class Lethe Scenario: a scenario where a memetic phenomenon called [scp-3848](http://www.scpwiki.com/scp-3848) causes [people to forget basic activities](http://www.scp-wiki.net/amnesticization) and act strangely because of it. The [TvTropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TheEndOfTheWorldAsWeKnowIt/SCPFoundation) described how the phenomenon was able to "erase the concepts that make up normal human morality, having some of the infected exhibit Blue and Orange Morality". I, however, was not able to identify instances of moral behavior being changed by the virus, just instances of people acting silly because they [forgot how to fly fish](http://www.scp-wiki.net/paperpushing) and those not affected calling the infected people weird. Am I missing something from this particular SCP tale and are there any specific instances in these stories of scp-3848 changing human morality or causing '[Blue and Orange Morality](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlueAndOrangeMorality)' that I overlooked?

Comment: "*Description of Concept Affected: The fact that murder is illegal, as well as the fact that it is generally regarded as amoral.*" - This seems like a fairly big change in morality

Comment: Besides, I don't understand what you are saying. Where does it indicate that the phenomenon is a virus? Where do people decide to flee Earth?

Comment: @Adamant: sorry, I fixed it. There was another story connected to scp-3848 where it was described as 'like a virus' and people left Earth because of it in an alternate reality.  I edited this out since it is not relevant to the current question and what I was asking for.

Comment: Links to TVTropes should perhaps be marked with a warning that any such link constitutes "memetic activity" that "causes people to forget basic activities". ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different items in the story of SCP-3848 that show a difference in morality or at least personal behavior. One instance of SCP-3848 in Wisconsin, for example, led to everyone forgetting the existence of canines, causing people [to become fearful of dogs and unable to care for their own pets](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-3848). Their reaction to all dog breeds, even friendly ones, became fear and/or fascination with the concept of dogs in a way many people (especially in the United States where dogs are plentiful and generally considered 'man's best friend') would find very peculiar. Also, in Ontario, Canada on January 3rd, 2017 -as another contributor pointed out - a select group of people started killing their neighbors and fellow townsmen while forgetting that murder is illegal and generally considered amoral.